# При нажатии на button создавать блок div с содержимым input-a

Tags: javascript, dom, html

```
    <input type="text" id="in"> //**ввод текста-комментария**
    <button id="add">Add</button>//**добавление текста-комментария**
    <div id="out" class="out"></div>// **по идее должен был быть контейнером**
```

> Дальше идет скрипт: 
>   -----тут непосредственно добавляются значения в localstorage-----

```
window.onload = function() {

    var todoList=[];
    if (localStorage.getItem('todo')!=undefined){
        todoList=   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
        out()
    }
  document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {
        var d=document.getElementById('in').value;
        var temp={};
        temp.todo=d;
        temp.check=false;
        var i=todoList.length;
        todoList[i]=temp;
        console.log(todoList);
        out();
        localStorage.setItem('todo',    JSON.stringify(todoList));
    }


    }
```

> а вот функция, которая просто выводит один за одним текст, где не
>   удается сделать отдельные блоки  с содержимым input-ов

```
    function out() {
        let container=document.createElement('div');
        container.className="container";
        var out='';
        for (var key in todoList){
            out+=todoList[key].todo+"<br>";
        }
        container.innerHTML=out;
        document.getElementById('out').appendChild(container)
    // container.appendChild=out;
}

}
```

> Для пояснения: я хочу сделать что-то вроде блога и эта реализация
>   нужна для добавления записей на странице.

Comment: но ведь localstorage у каждого свой

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, наверное?

```js
function out() {
    let value = document.getElementById('input').value
    if (!value)
      return;
    let container=document.createElement('div');
    container.className = "container";
    container.innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(container)
}
```

```css
.container{
  border:solid 1px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:  center;
  margin:5px 0  5px 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="input"><button onclick="out()">add</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Добрый день) заранее спасибо за попытку помочь, попробовала ваш первый вариант - вышло, что у меня  в каждом блоке добавлялось по n+1 out-ов, то есть я ввела в инпут текст  и в новом блоке появлялись все предыдущие + новый.  Дело в том что у меня есть массив обьектов, куда я заношу значения через инпут и сохраняю в localstorage. Оттуда через переменную out я вывожу содержимое. И вот его я хочу переместить в блок, при этом, чтобы для каждого нового блока был только новый текст из инпута. Здесь где-то можно еще прикрепить пример кода?

Comment: @МарьямСерватманд добавляйте в вопрос

Comment: спасибо, добавила